# osx python - how do I decode sys.argv?

Tags: python, macos

I don't think I'm even using funky characters - just trying to pass in a "-d" but my dash seems to get munged.  If I just print sys.argv[1] it looks okay, but if I print the entire list sys.argv, I can see funky characters instead of my dash.
Mac OSX 10.6.8
Python 2.6.1

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        print "SVH FLAG sys.argv ",sys.argv

        num_args = len(sys.argv)
        for i in range(0,num_args):
            print "SVH FLAG sys.argv[",i,"] ",sys.argv[i]

    except:
        print "problem with sys.argv"
```

Which gives me this when I call it with -d:
./deleteme.py –d /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages

```
SVH FLAG sys.argv  ['./deleteme.py', '\xe2\x80\x93d', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages']
SVH FLAG sys.argv[ 0 ]  ./deleteme.py
SVH FLAG sys.argv[ 1 ]  –d
SVH FLAG sys.argv[ 2 ]  /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

That funky string on the first line of output seems to really mess up something like optparse, which doesn't see my dash.

Is there something I need to tell sys to give me a normal looking argv?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you typing that dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, you are not typing a hyphen, but an actual dash character (option -), Unicode 8211, whose UTF-8 representation is the three-byte string `\xe2\x80\x93`. We always refer to the character that precedes command-line options as a "dash", but it's really a hyphen!

Comment: Copy-and-paste from MS Office?

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was it.  I cut-and-pasted my -d /path from a webpage and that page must have had the option -.  That'll teach me to cut-and-paste...

Answer (score 1):

Are you copy pasting this? I just took the first two dashes from

`Which gives me this when I call it with -d: ./deleteme.py –d /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages`

```
python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '–'
'\xe2\x80\x93'
>>> '-'
'-'
>>>
```

Did this come from a word doc or pdf or something? Retype it and you should be fine.